partial function template specialization with templated object as function argument
suppose i have this class :
template <typename T> class MyClass{
}

template <typename T> class MyOtherClass{
}

and some generic template function
template <typename A> void someFuncT(const A& arg){ //generic function template
    //... body here
}

I want to specialize A for MyClass<T>, but doing this, will be error
template<> template <typename T> void someFuncT(const MyClass<T>& arg){ //specialized for A = MyClass<T>
    //... body here
}

on the other side, doing this is okay
template <typename T> void someFuncT(const MyClass<T>& arg){
    //... body here
}

template <typename T> void someFuncT(const MyOtherClass<T>& arg){
    //... body here
}

but it will be ambiguous for :
MyOtherClass other;
someFuncT<MyOtherClass>(other);

which could create :
void someFuncT(const MyClass<MyOtherClass>& arg){ }

but the intention is to create a specialized template for A = MyOtherClass, so :
void someFuncT(const MyOtherClass& arg){}

so how to do function template specialization if one of the arguments of the function is a class with another template ?

but doing this, will be error -- function specializations are not allowed. on the other side, doing this is okay -- they actually are overloaded functions, this is allowed.

yeah i know that is overloaded function just an alternative solution to the problem, but the overloaded function with template can't solve it too, also if the function template argument type does not have templated type, it work just fine, so I think template function specialization is allowed

Be kind to post a [mre] that you are trying to solve. And fix the missing semicolons and template parameters in the shown code snippets. W/o a [mre], the question has no object to answer to.

@3CxEZiVlQ It's "partial" specialization that is not allowed. But specialization(including explicit) is allowed.
